# Disable Outlook Email Forwarding in Java

Tags: java, spring, email

In Outlook there are options to disabled replying to and forwarding of emails.  Granted this is only a rudimentary level of security as someone can always copy / paste the email content, but it does prevent accidental forwarding of confidential emails.

My question is how can these options be disabled when sending a mail using Java?  I am using Spring's `JavaMailSenderImpl` but could move to a different library if required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How could application options in Outlook translate to sending mail from javamail?

Comment: Presumably some information is written into the email header by Outlook to disable the "Forward" option on the email recipient's machine.  I'd like to use a Java API to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this on Scott Hanselman's [blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToEasilyDisableReplyToAllAndForwardInOutlook.aspx), suggesting that this information isn't written into the email header as I had hoped, which suggests to me that disabling forwarding would be very difficult in pure Java without some interaction through JNI:

*It only flips a metadata bit in the message and that metadata is only transmitted within Exchange (within your company). It is not propagated to outside email addresses.*

Comment: can you explain what is the way you think JNI can help?

Answer (score 2):

Taking a look about and it appears that this is a feature of [Microsoft Windows Rights Management Services](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/evaluation/overview/technologies/rmenterprise.mspx) so would likely require talking to that rather than just setting a header. But to test that send yourself a mail to say a GMail account and then use the "view original" option.